# Duplicate Java Annotation Exception

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to write an AnnotationProcessor class which extends AbstractProcessor.
And i am trying to process customized annotation and errors.

I know java does not allow any duplicate annotation and return an compiler Error according to the image below.

Anyway i can catch this exception and and display a customized error message?

[image: Duplicate Annotation Exception]

Answer (score 0):

That is not an exception, but a compilation error; your code wouldn't even compile